# Javascript - Passing from a DOM element to array

Tags: javascript, dom, innerhtml, getelementsbyclassname

Hello and thank you for your time.

Here is the code :

```
<script>
var names = document.getElementsByClassName('xx');
var ar = [];
for (var i = 0, c = names.length ; i < c ; i++) {
ar[i] = names[i].innerHTML;
alert(ar[i]);// the results are : undefined
}
</script>`
```

I've tried to use the method tostring, or to push the results into the array but without success.

Thanks

Comment: You are probably getting a syntax error in this code, or it is a typo?

Comment: You're missing a closing curly brace '}'

Comment: `ar` has a length of `0`. `i` is equal to `0`. your for loop will not iterate.

Comment: and you're taking the length of 'ar' instead of names. The length of ar is 0

Comment: Read carefully the http://stackoverflow.com/tour and http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: no syntax error it works when I call the function alert(names[i].innerHTML); and my curly brace closes after in the code.

Comment: As Moritz says, you need `c = names.length`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main issue seems to be fixed. Make sure the DOM has been loaded before you try to run your code, and there is no need for two variables in your loop. Simplify it like below:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var names = document.getElementsByClassName('xx');
    var ar = [];

    for (var i = 0 ; i < names.length ; i++) {
        ar[i] = names[i].innerHTML;
        alert(ar[i]);
    }
};
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g529r9rg/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was the window.onload function that I was missing.

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help. Please accept answer if this solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

ar.length equals 0, because you just declare the array, but dont put anything into it. I think what you wanted to do is the following:

```
var names = document.getElementsByClassName('xx');
var ar = [];
for (var i = 0 ; i < names.length ; i++) {
ar[i] = names[i].innerHTML;
alert(ar[i]);
}
```

Comment: Yes that's right. And when I do this i get an array with undefined everywhere. But when I do alert(names[i].innerHTML); it works. I don't know it's very strange

Comment: Put your script tag at the end of your document, instead of the beginning. So put it after </body>